# Visual Studio 2013 Custom project Web Template does not displayed

Tags: visual-studio

I'm creating a project template for web on visual studio 2013 Update 4. 
I create a project of "C# Project Template" type. 
I edit the vstemplate file to: (As described at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171386.aspx)

```
 <ProjectType>Web</ProjectType>
 <ProjectSubType>CSharp</ProjectSubType>
```

Then I added a vsix project and add it an asset, the template project.
This is the vsixmanifest assets section in xml editor:

```
<Assets>
    <Asset Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectTemplate" d:Source="Project" d:ProjectName="MyTestProjectTemplate" d:TargetPath="|MyTestProjectTemplate;TemplateProjectOutputGroup|" Path="ProjectTemplates" d:VsixSubPath="ProjectTemplates" />
</Assets>
```

If I sign the ProjectType as CSharp the project template is listed under "CSharp" but when it's listed as web as desribed above it's not displayed at all. 
**Any ideas?**

Answer (score 1):

I hope it will help someone. 
You have to set the vstemplate:

```
<ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
<TemplateGroupID>Web</TemplateGroupID>
```

In the vstemplate file properties (F4) (Solution Explorer) you have to set the Category to web. 
If you will examine the compilation result output it's now :

```
 bin\Debug\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Web\1033\<Your Template Zip>
```

Check out the **csproj file of the template project** and you will see:

```
<ItemGroup>
      <VSTemplate Include="MyTestProjectTemplate.vstemplate">
           <SubType>Designer</SubType>
           <OutputSubPath>Web</OutputSubPath>
      </VSTemplate>
 </ItemGroup>
```

This is the  Category-> Web result. (I wondered why I don't see this definition effect it in the vstemplate file... so this is the answer. It's a definition in the csproj file).
Add the vsix and the project as a project template asset and it works as expected. 
When we understand that the issue is the path that the template zip is in it's much simpler and can be solved for multiple project template as well. 
***Now to a multiple project template!***

In this scenario you have a zip file with root vstemplate and sub folder for each contained project.

1. **The root vstemplate file** has to be signed with:

   ```
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
    <TemplateGroupID>Web</TemplateGroupID>
   ```
2. At the vsix project folder you have to add the following folders: (Close visual studio and do it outside visual studio in windows).

   ```
   ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Web\1033
   ```
3. Add your template zip under the folder 1033. (Outside visual studio)
4. Open visual studio, select "Show All Files" in the solution explorer pane. 
    Roll down to your template zip file in the vsix project, right click and select "Include in project".
5. At the template zip file properties, change the Build Action to Content, Copy Always and Include in VSIX to true.
6. At the vsixmanifest editor (double click it), Add asset. 
   Project Template->File on filesystem->The path to your zip (Has to be already  in the drop down box as an option).
7. Compile the vsix project. Open the output folder (Usually bin\debug) and see that the result is vsix file at the root folder and the following folders tree next to it. ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Web\1033\.
8. Run the vsix and see the project template under "Web".
9. A moment of silence. Let's remember the programmers that fell in this bloody battle. :-)